# How to force equal spaces around French quotation marks?

Tags: spacing, xetex, symbols, polyglossia, white-space

this is again a noob question, and I guess a very generic one.
In my French text, I use French quotation marks (the opening one is followed by a non-breaking space, the closing one is preceded by one).

My issue is that those non-breaking spaces are used as regular blank spaces, to adjust the width of a line, which results in uneven spaces between the quotation marks (guillemets) and the quoted text, which is really ugly:

[image]

Is there a way to force LaTeX to make those 2 non-breaking spaces the same width at least for a single pair of quotation marks?

EDIT:

I have manually inserted non-breaking spaces at relevant places around punctuation marks:

```
 les deux jeunes «~Picards~» Michel et Guibert
```

What bothers me is that those spaces are stretched unevenly.
I have to use XeLaTeX,

Comment: If you use babel french option it should take care of the space around punctuation without you adding any spaces by hand. As you have shown no code it is hard to know what you have done here.

Comment: OK, I am not using babel, I am looking it up but it seems incompatible with XeLaTex, which I have to use... I am using polyglossia and inputenc in UTF8. I did not know about automatic spacing for French punctuation, so I inserted a non-breaking space after / before the relevant marks. The spaces are there, it's how those spaces are strecthed unevenly that bothers me

Comment: You still have not shown your document or how you have set up french.  babel is not incompatible with xelatex, it is the standard latex language support system. but polyglossia is an alternative. Either way you should not be inserting no breaking spaces.

Comment: Anyway, the spacing should be a *thin* non-breakablespace (`«\,…\,»`).

Comment: as Bernard says `~` is the wrong space in any case but all `~` on a line will stretch by the same amount Your image looks like you have a space next to one of the `~` but as you have not provided any code that reproduces the problem, it is hard to say. In any case you should let latex add the spaces.

Comment: note also you should not use inputenc with xelatex (it does nothing other than generate a warning saying that it should not be used)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can tell `babel-french` to use `«»` for the guillemets, but there is also a “command form”.

Note that whether you use spaces after `«` or before `»` is immaterial; however, remember “backslash-space” after `\fg` if you want a space when you use the command form.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\frenchsetup{og=«,fg=»}

\begin{document}

les deux jeunes «Picards» Michel et Guibert

les deux jeunes « Picards » Michel et Guibert

les deux jeunes \og Picards \fg\ Michel et Guibert

\end{document}
```

[image]

Or you can use `polyglossia` instead of `babel`, but in this case there is no “command form”.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setmainlanguage{french}

\begin{document}

les deux jeunes «Picards» Michel et Guibert

les deux jeunes « Picards » Michel et Guibert

\end{document}
```

For completeness, here's with `pdflatex`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}

% use « and » for guillemets
\frenchsetup{
  og=«,
  fg=»,
}


\begin{document}

les deux jeunes «Picards» Michel et Guibert

les deux jeunes « Picards » Michel et Guibert

les deux jeunes \og Picards \fg\ Michel et Guibert

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, is it compatible with XeLaTeX (which I have to use)? I am trying to implement the example but I keep getting "! Package babel Error: You haven't defined the language [ yet." (although I have)

Comment: @user1940642 I edited to match the XeLaTeX requirement.

Comment: Thanks, problem solved! I had all the right things in the preamble, but my manually inserted non-breaking spaces were messing things up! Now that I have deleted them, it looks as it should.

Comment: The syntax to switch languages in `polyglossia` isn't compatible with that of `babel`. Very likely the error you are getting is because of that, because `babel` works with the 3 main engines (pdf/xe/lua).

Answer (score 6):

The `csquotes` package provides the command `\enquote` that should be of interest to you.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia} % load 'fontspec' automatically
\setmainlanguage{french}
\usepackage[french=guillemets]{csquotes}

\begin{document}
les deux jeunes \enquote{Picards} Michel et Guibert
\end{document}
```