# Space before and after a non-breaking space are different

Tags: white-space

I want to use a non-breaking space within a pair of guillemets. But the space within these guillemets are not equal. If I remove the guillemets, the spaces are equal and this looks good to me. If I remove the non-breaking space, it looks good too.
The following code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\begin{document}

Les crochets \og~[~\fg et \og~]~\fg 

Les crochets~[~et~]~ 

Les crochets \og [ \fg et \og ] \fg 

\end{document}
```

produces:

[image: Unequal spaces]

The space before the square bracket is larger than the space after. It does not look nice to me, but I cannot understand why it is produced and how to fix it.

Comment: The space after `\og` is automatically a non-breaking space (cf. p.13, [babel-french](https://texdoc.org/serve/frenchb-doc.pdf/0)).

Comment: Ditto for the space before `\fg` (see `\FB@guillspace` in french.ldf). [This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/596148/73317) (egreg) would probably help Michael.

Comment: Just use `«` and `»`. But if you want to make your life more difficult, add ***no*** `~` after `\og` nor before `\fg`.